# Minimize and Maximize Windows Form application

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I am using VC++ in visual studio for making a GUI. There is option like WindowState but dont know how to use it through code. I am configuring pixturebox as buttons and I want to minimize and maximize the application whenever I click it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the answer its

```
WindowState = FormWindowState::Maximized;
```